# Excel User Function to return a value based on last number in column

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

Function Purpose: Return a number value which is the sum of the number above it in the column + 1. This function will be used to number the item number when I add an "item" (a copied form, which will include the function in a cell to automatically number it). If it is the first item in my table (row 6) it should be a 0.

Problem: Returning a value of 0 regardless, Column A, where the function will be located can contain 3 different things, A string, blank space or a number.
This is an example of where the function would be used.

The space inbetween 0's varies, where it can be anything from no space to 100.

[image]
[image]

Code,

```
Public Function ItemNum() As Integer

Dim loc As range
Dim numChkCell As range
Set loc = Application.Caller


If loc.Row = 7 Then
    ItemNum = 1
    Exit Function
End If
Set numChkCell = loc.Offset(-1, 0)

Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(numChkCell) = False
    If (numChkCell.Value <> loc.Value2 And 
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(numChkCell) = True) Then
     ItemNum = numChkCell.Value2 + 1

     Exit Do
    Else
     Set numChkCell = numChkCell.Offset(-1, 0)
    End If
 Loop
 ItemNum = numChkCell.Value2 + 1
End Function
```

Comment: It sounds like this can be done with in sheet formulas.  Can you please provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: I have edited to show an example, I thought it could be done with in sheet formulas the only problem is that the range changes constantly and rows will be cut out and pasted etc....

Comment: Numbers in red are what I would like, simply adding 1 to the number above it.

Comment: In cell A7 and copied down: `=COUNTIF($B$7:$B7,0)`

Comment: That works, except for when it encounters  a "QI" row, where the value in B for that is also a 0. I may be able to take away that 0 but it could mess up the rest of my sheet. Is there anyway to add a criteria that it the corresponding cell in A cant be "QI?"